# How to make an instance of a class without using new keyword?

Tags: c#

Lets say i have a class like below

```
public Class Person
{
  public string Firstname { set; get; }
  public string Lastname { set; get; }
}
```

Here is the question, how can i get the instance from Person class like below ?

```
Person p = "AAAA BBBB";
```

So now, Firstname is equal to AAAA and Lastname is equal to BBBB, I do not want to use constructor in my class,first of all, is it possible to do so ? then how?

Comment: Why do you don't want to use Constructor? What do you mean by that? You mean you don't want to add parameterized constructor or you don't at all want to call any constructor?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I presume he wants to use the default constructor.

Comment: @slugster No assumptions with questions like this. If he don't at all want to use the default constructor answer would be different. That's why am asking for clarification..

Comment: yes, lets say we have int m=15, how can i make a class so i can initialize my class like int type ?

Comment: @slugster It turns out OP is asking for [implicit operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505190/how-without-using-constructors-initialize-the-class#comment39812750_25505241)

Comment: @Behzad You have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25505296/2530848)

Comment: @Behzad but you have to see **one big difference**: `15` IS an integer (`int`) while `"AAA BBB"` IS NOT `Person` because it's a `string`. It doesn't make more sense than `int i = "1"`. Can you see what I mean? That's why you need a conversion operator for that. Finally don't forget that interpretation is pretty arbitrary: what if name is "Jon Carlos Smith Jr"? Which part is given name and which part is  family name?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I can see that... good answer from Dmitrey.

Comment: thanks to Dmitrey :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement *operator* (C#):

```
public class Person
{
  public string Firstname { set; get; }
  public string Lastname { set; get; }

  public static implicit operator Person(String value) {
    Person result = new Person();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      return result;

    //TODO: More elaborated code required: check if there's no space, two or more spaces etc. 
    String[] items = value.Split(' ');

    result.Firstname = items[0];
    result.Lastname = items[1];

    return result;
  }
}

...

Person sample = "AAAA BBBB";
```

Comment: This would cause a problem if there's no space in the given string. Also, spelling error: implicit, not impicit.

Comment: tnx :) that was what i was looking for. i know i was not clear enough in my question

Comment: @RvdK to be sure they will sell a patch first time someone will enter "Rose Mary Smith"...

Comment: @Behzad Implicit conversions shouldn't throw any exception. But here you can't make it work without throwing exceptions. What should your code do when someone says `Person p = "***"`? Well, you can add a try/catch but that doesn't mean you've constructed a valid `Person` object from `***`

Comment: @Behzad now you know you _may_ do it and you learned about implicit custom conversion operators. Good. **Remember that but don't do it** for this. It's not _sugar_ for you code but a source of (not so) subtle bugs.

Comment: the person class was just an example ;) i need it for converting time to different formats(lets say HH:MM:SS or HH:MM or HH.MM or HH.MM.SS), tnx anyway

Comment: Please use the DateTime class for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx . Always explain the exact usecase. There are probably other ways to fix what you want. This is clearly not what you want, it will create chaos in your application!

Comment: @RvdK i know what i want, i cant use datetime since i do not have a specific format for my time

Comment: Check the link, it is TryParse. It tries to parse according to defined format.

Comment: Excellent answer!! I thought OP was unsure about what he wanted, didn't know this was possible at all.

Comment: @Behzad if you have a DateTime then it's one more reason to avoid such conversion. Conversions aren't implicit for a reason (in this case: it may fail, it's arbitrary AND it's culture dependant)! Something you should always avoid in your code...it's not trivial then it must be explicit and clear. Which kind of comparison string1==string2 performs? Too many people can't answer without checking documentation but you see it too often in code. Is string1.Length == number of characters? No. "Easy" doesn't always mean good.

Comment: Of course this is just my opinion but I don't trust myself then I prefer to immediately see when I'm doing something "dangerous". I don't have to remember. I don't have to understand. There isn't anything obscure. It's there highlighted in my code: "WARNING, it's not such easy."

Comment: Let me be more clear, In my application, the time shows as HH:MM format, since i am using several web services, in each of them the time format is different, so for serialization and deserialization i need to go through my classes to do the time conversation, it is possible for me to use TryParse in every class but imagine for every new webservice i need to make the conversation separately, but if i have a class (lets say MY-Time Class), then i do not need to do such a conversation in every of them and the class do the conversation by it self, Let me know if my approach is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a class without a constructor. That's what a constructor is for.

You can however initialize a Person object and set its properties in 1 statement:

```
Person p = new Person { FirstName = "AAAA", LastName = "BBBB" };
```